# Examining whether a circle goes through any of a given set of points

Tags: geometry, circles

In a rectangular coordinate system, the circle is created at the central and passes through point $P(0,-3)$. Which of the following points does it also pass through?

1. $(3,3)$
2. $(-2 \sqrt 2,-1)$
3. $(2,6)$
4. $(- \sqrt 3, \sqrt 3)$
5. $(-3,4)$

Comment: Any thoughts?  Note:  I am guessing that "created at the central" means that the center is $(0,0)$ but of course that is just a guess.

Comment: well, the question does not provide any additional information. And i am about to imply that too

Comment: Can you check if any of them solve $x^2+y^2=9$

Comment: So, with that assumption, what have you tried?  Do you know what the analytic definition of a circle is?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, can you explain why it needs to satisfy x2+y2=9 ?

Comment: All circles centered at $(0,0)$ are of the form $x^2+y^2=r^2$. As it passes through $P$, the radius is $3$ so our equation becomes $x^2+y^2=9$

Comment: I figure it out, thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

If, indeed, "created at the central" means "centered at the origin" as you think, then we know the circle has center $(0,0)$. Since it goes through $(0,-3)$, we can conclude it has radius $3$. Accordingly, recall the general form for a circle in the plane:

$$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$$

where $(h,k)$ is the center, and $r$ the radius. With the knowledge $(h,k)=(0,0)$ and $r=3$ as described previously, create the equation for the circle, and then plug in each point you're given, seeing if each creates a true statement.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation